# My regex expression is both lazy and greedy. Why?

Tags: regex

Suppose I'm searching for anchor links in a web page. A regex that works is:

```
 "\<a\s+.*?\>"
```

However, lets add a complication.  Lets suppose that I only want links which surround specific text, for instance, the word 'next'.  Normally, I would think all I had to do is:

```
 "\<a\s+.*?\>next"
```

But I find that now, if there are 3 anchor tags in a page, and the third one has 'next' after it, that the regex search finds a huge string extending from the first anchor tag, and extending to the third anchor tag.   This makes sense if the period-asterisk-questionmark is finding all characters until it comes across ">next".  But that is not what I want.  I want to find all characters until it comes across ">", and then an additional constraint should be that right after the ">" there should be "next".

How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can fix your regex by prohibiting it from matching `>` inside the tag, i.e. by replacing `.` with `[^>]`:

```
"\<a\s+[^>]*?\>next"
```

`.*?` matches any number of characters. The fact that you made it reluctant does not make it stop at `>`: it continues matching past it, until it finds `>next` at the end. This is not greedy, because the expression matched as little as possible to obtain a match. It's just that no shorter matches were available.

[Demo.](https://regex101.com/r/gW8dO3/1)